# Accessing the Database Row of the Current User

Tags: mysql, sql, database, parse-platform, backend

I manually added fields to my "_User" table on Parse. Specifically, a Twitter Handle that is a string and has the key "TwitterHandle." For some reason, when I execute the following statement (and the Twitter Handle is non-null), I receive null:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"TwitterHandle"]);
```

Instead, I have to execute the following code, querying the backend to find the current user's fields, and their twitter handle specifically, which seems redundant and overly complicated:

```
PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"_User"];
[query whereKey:@"username" equalTo:currentUser.username];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
  // do some stuff here with the current user's row in the User table, the only object in      
  // the NSArray of *objects
  NSLog(@"%@", [[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"TwitterHandle"]); --> (non-null)
}];
```

Is it because of the way I set up the field, manually? Otherwise, I'm not sure why my code is exhibiting this behavior.

Comment: did you edit the user to add that field in the data browser?.. if so you should be able to just fetch the new data with [[PFUser currentUser] fetchInBackground];

Comment: What do you mean by "edit the user?" @Fosco I was able to populate those fields in the backend by saving the user in the background after receiving their twitter handle. I have never seen the fetchInBackground method, though.  

Would this have all been solved if I did it in code, like:   [[PFUser currentUser] setObject:self.twitterField.text forKey:@"TwitterHandle"];

Comment: Yeah that should do it...  what if you NSLog(@"%@", [PFUser currentUser]);.

Comment: @Fosco it comes up as something like <PFUser:(objectId):(null) { username = (username) }

Comment: strange.. it's not set.  You're sure you SET and SAVED on the currentUser?..  you should try fetch'ing it and see if it sticks.

Comment: @Fosco Yes, I have called the setObject:forKey: instance method on the currentUser, and I have saved it in the background with a block. I will indeed try, but I think it has to do with my manually adding a column to the "_User" table, when that could have been automatically done. I was also using syntax (in some, rare instances) like object[@"TwitterHandle"] = self.twitterHandleField.text; [object saveInBackground]; I do not know if that syntax necessarily works.

Answer (score 0):

The `currentUser` object is populated at login and cached, if the data is changing you will need to fetch the latest copy:

```
[[PFUser currentUser] fetchInBackground];
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned by Timothy `[[PFUser currentUser] fetchInBackground];` will get new column at the expense of a request to Parse.

However, while developping, Logout from the app and log back in. This will clear the cache and retrieve all USER info.